# Introducing a new container to a docker environment interferes with other containers

Tags: docker, tomcat, docker-compose, hazelcast, docker-network

I’ve spent an awful long time trying to debug this. I have an already populated docker compose file with multiple containers running, all on the same network. The containers consist of a tomcat9 server(Server A), a hazelcast container, and a hazelcast-mancenter container, and then an apache server.
I want to introduce an additional container, which is a tomcat7 server(Server B), and for some reason it interferes with the original tomcat server(Server A). Server A never gets to a start up state when server B's container is running.

Whenever Server B is off, Server A works no problem(after a restart). The moment Server B comes on, Server A poops out.

For some reason Server B also attempts to connect to Hazelcast or affects it.  Even if I take Server B off the network as the other containers, there is still interference. I am certain that Server B is not attempting to connect to the original Hazelcast container.

What is going on? Shouldn’t the container be isolated?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  server_a_tomcat:
    container_name: server_a_tomcat
    image: server_a:latest
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "5005:5005"
    networks:
    - network_a
    depends_on:
      - server_a_mountebank_local
    volumes:
      - …/java-config
      - …/server_a_tomcat.war      
      - data-volume:/usr/local/ssl
    environment:
      - …
  server_a_mountebank_local:
    container_name: server_a_mountebank_local
    image: mountebank:latest
    volumes:
    - …
    networks:
    - network_a
    ports:
    - "8083:8083"
  apache_local:
    container_name: apache_local
    image: apache_local:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8055:8055"
    depends_on:
      - server_a_local
    volumes:
      - …/httpd.conf
      - …/extra-httpd.conf
      - …
      - data-volume:/usr/local/ssl
    networks:
    - network_a
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  hazelcast_local:
    container_name: hazelcast_local
    image: hazelcast_local:latest
    ports:
      - 11415:5701
    depends_on:
      - mancenter_local
  mancenter_local:
    container_name: mancenter_local
    image: mancenter_local:latest
    environment:
      - HAZELCAST_IP={{ container_private_ip }}
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Dhazelcast.mc.rest.enabled=true
    ports:
      - 8100:8080
    networks:
      - network_a
  server_b_tomcat:
    container_name: server_b_tomcat
    build: 
      context: '.'
      dockerfile: 'Dockerfile-server_b_tomcat’
    ports:
    - "9090:8080"
    - "5015:5005"
    environment: 
      - ...
    networks:
      - network_b
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: redis:5.0.5
    ports: 
    - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - network_b
networks:
  network_b:
    driver: bridge
    name: network_b
  network_a:
    driver: bridge
    name: network_a
volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Comment: It's impossible to be of any help without the docker-compose.yml file itself.

Comment: @Nicolas I've updated the post to include a docker compose file

Comment: Did you check the logs of server_a_tomcat? Do you have enough resources to hold both servers? (check kernel logs for OOM messages).

Comment: Yeah server_a_tomcat's log ends up stalling out midway through, meaning I never see `Server Started` message. I will check on the resources. Didn't think about that.

Comment: @codestation I don't see anything unusual in the kernel logs.